# Create my own queue using node

Tags: java

So as the topic tells I am trying to create my own queue. If I just had the brainjuice left tonight I probably could've figured it ou.. but that's not the case and I can't let it go haha!

```
public class Queue<E> {
    private Node<E> start;
    private Node<E> queue;
    private int length;

    public void enqueue(E element) {
        if (start != null) {
            length++;
            this.queue = new Node<E>(element, queue);
            start.setNext(queue);
        } else {
            length++;
            this.start = new Node<E>(element, null);
        }
    }
    public E dequeue() throws Empxception {
        if (start != null) {
            Node<E> temp = start;
            start = start.getNext();
            length--;
            return temp.getElement();
        } else {
            throw new Empxception("Empty queue");
        }
    }
```

So when I give an input like: 1, 9, 9 & 6 the output from dequeue is 1, 6, 9 & 9. Where did I fail?

Comment: `start.setNext(queue);` does not make any sense, `start` will always stay the same and you therefore insert all new elements right behind it at "index" 1.

Comment: Ops. Forgot about my node-class, so start.setNext() is a setNext-method in my node-class. Shouldn't start refer to the next input?